# Customize build and release role in maven

Tags: maven

I have a Non-Java Maven project. By default the deploy goal generates a JAR file, however I would like to generate a zip file instead that should be published to nexus at a later phase.

If I create the zip file manually and place it in the target folder, Maven is not publishing it to nexus, it only publishes the JAR file automatically created.

So my question is: Is there any way to upload to nexus all the content of the target folder? If not, how do I tell Maven not to create a jar file and create a custom zip instead?

Comment: You can use build-helper-maven-plugin to attach it to your Maven project and by using that it will be later deployed by `mvn deploy`..The other question is why are not creating the zip file via Maven (maven-assembly-plugin) ?

Comment: I will check the build-helper-maven-plugin. As for the assembly plugin, I dont want to use it, because it handles only zip files.. In the future, I will have to deploy to nexus some other formats

Comment: What do you mean by `it handles only zip files..`?

Comment: I meant it only handles creating compressed file. The zip file I intend to deploy on nexus will be generated by a script. It is not only a simple zip of some file.

Comment: The question why is it generated by a script an not by Java code? Or why not creating the zip file by assembly plugin? What is so sophisticated about that zip file?

Comment: Hi, the project I am building is not a java project. It is based on a software called talend, and the script which creates the zip file is provided by the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Maven has the `deploy:deploy-file` goal which can be configured in your `pom.xml` It can be used to upload arbitrary files, including zips.

You can avoid the creation of a jar if you change `<packaging>` to `pom`.

Comment: Hi, deploy-file was my first choice. It is working for snapshots but not for releases. When I release my zip to nexus with the release version, I get an error because the release version was already used by the default deployment: